# Get all documents of a collection using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to write a function to return all the documents contained in `mycollection` in mongodb

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
    db=client.mydatabase
    collection=db['mycollection']
    cursor = collection.find({})
    for document in cursor:
        print(document)
```

However, the function returns: `Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: have you tried without braces in the find method? try cursor = db.mycollection.find()

Comment: the same result :
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Ok, how are you executing this script? (Also please adjust the indentation)

Comment: I'm using Pycharm 2.0.3

Comment: Ok this is a pycharm specific usage problem because your code is fine. Also check that you run directly your script as the main one, since you have \__name\__ == '\__main\__' in your code, try using a console to check the connectivity with the database.

Comment: I checked the connectivity and It's OK. SO, I could print all collection of my database

Comment: Yes, you can print all the documents in the collection.

Comment: how I can do this? It returns the same output : Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I tried the same code as OP posted in my Linux machine with different db and collection. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 108):

Here is the sample code which works fine when you run from command prompt.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017, maxPoolSize=50)
    db = client.localhost
    collection = db['chain']
    cursor = collection.find({})
    for document in cursor:
          print(document)
```

**Please check the collection name.**

Comment: It the same what I did

Comment: I have pasted the above code to confirm that there is no problem in the code. It is something to do with the local environment. Also, I mentioned that it works fine from command prompt.

Comment: I understand. Finally, it works
The problem was in the collection name
Thank you

Comment: Why are `json` and `pymongo` imported for this [mcve]?

Comment: This seem slow. Is there not a more performant way to download all the documents?

Answer (score 64):

pymongo creates a cursor. Hence you'll get the object 'under' the cursor. To get all objects in general try:

```
list(db.collection.find({}))
```

This will force the cursor to iterate over each object and put it in a list()

Have fun...

Answer (score 12):

I think this will work fine in your program.

```
cursor = db.mycollection # choosing the collection you need

for document in cursor.find():
    print (document)
```

Comment: Here `cursor = db.mycollection` do not name variable as cursor it would ideal to name as `collection`, Just not to confuse as `cursor.find():` should be `collection.find():` which returns a `cursor` that can be iterated over to get the values out.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me,try checking the exact database name and collection name.
and try changing from `db=client.mydatabase`  to `db=client['mydatabase']` .

If your database name is such that using attribute style access won’t work (like test-database), you can use dictionary style access instead.
[source](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) !